# Dynamic Multi Dimensional Array Object Convert to Single Array Object

Tags: php, arrays, object

When i call API i found this array object **"online_bill_list"** object is unknown to me. Please see details.

```
stdClass Object
(
[online_bill_list] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tbl_bill] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2081804
                [ClientID] => 01-001-0287-00
                [holdingNo] => 01-001-0287-00
                [billno] => 01-001-0287-0032017
                [date_month] => 2017-03-01T00:00:00
                [unit] => 0.0000
                [others] => 0.0000
                [fine] => 
                [due] => 
                [bill] => 250.0000
                [netbill] => 255.0000
                [payment_date] => 2017-04-30T00:00:00
                [inserted_date] => 2017-04-18T00:00:00
        )
    )
)
```

I want to convert this array in a single array object.

```
[tbl_bill] => stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2081804
    [ClientID] => 01-001-0287-00
    [holdingNo] => 01-001-0287-00
    [billno] => 01-001-0287-0032017
    [date_month] => 2017-03-01T00:00:00
    [unit] => 0.0000
    [others] => 0.0000
    [fine] => 
    [due] => 
    [bill] => 250.0000
    [netbill] => 255.0000
    [payment_date] => 2017-04-30T00:00:00
    [inserted_date] => 2017-04-18T00:00:00

)
```

Comment: `$single = $initial->online_bill_list->tbl_bill`

Comment: online_bill_list and tbl_bill is dynamic value is there anyway in PHP to convert multiple object array to single array object.

Answer (score 1):

Then all you have to do is pick the object you want out of the larger object

```
$tbl_bill = $BigObject->online_bill_list->tbl_bill;
```

Comment: Well with this the new variable `$tbl_bill` will be just the `tbl_bill` object. Thats what you wanted right?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pick the object you want. Please try the following examples.

Print the object

```
print_r($object->online_bill_list->tbl_bill);
```

Storing and printing the object.

```
$array = $object->online_bill_list->tbl_bill;
print_r($array);
```